# Split string into Sub String

Tags: vb.net

I Am Using Vb.net. My idea is when I paste (ctrl+v) for example this character :

AHAKAPATARAE

I Have 6 textboxes.
it would automatically paste them in textboxes one by one in order!

so 
txtBox1 will contain : AH

txtBox2 : AK

txtBox3 : AP

txtBox4 : AT

texbox5 : AR

texbox6 : AE

The automation of inserting Licence Keys will ease so much
so that user will not work so hard to cut & paste each two digits!

so any suggestion of doing auto-fill inside textboxes..?

Thanks.

Comment: use a loop or linq to get parts of the string by indexes.

Comment: How to use loop in this.??

Comment: What type of app is this?  WinForms, WebForms, something else?....

Comment: Whats the purpose of individual boxes, why not check the whole thing? Also show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow the paste into the first textbox, as well as move forward correctly if the user types the whole thing manually starting in the first box:

```
Private Sub txtBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtBox6.TextChanged, txtBox5.TextChanged, txtBox4.TextChanged, txtBox3.TextChanged, txtBox2.TextChanged, txtBox1.TextChanged
    Dim TB As TextBox = DirectCast(sender, TextBox)
    Dim value As String = TB.Text
    If value.Length > 2 Then
        TB.Text = value.Substring(0, 2)
        Dim TBs() As TextBox = {txtBox1, txtBox2, txtBox3, txtBox4, txtBox5, txtBox6}
        Dim index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(TBs, TB)
        If index > -1 AndAlso index < (TBs.Length - 1) Then
            index = index + 1
            TBs(index).Text = value.Substring(2)
            TBs(index).Focus()
            TBs(index).SelectionStart = TBs(index).TextLength
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

There are definitely many more ways this could be accomplished...

Answer (score 0):

Handle the key down event on textbox 1

```
Private Sub txtBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles txtBox1.KeyDown
If e.Modifiers = Keys.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then

    ' Get Clipboard Text
    Dim cpText as String = My.Computer.Clipboard.GetText()

    ' Assign
    txtBox1.Text = cpText.Substring(0, 2)
    txtBox2.Text = cpText.Substring(2, 2)
    txtBox3.Text = cpText.Substring(4, 2)
    txtBox4.Text = cpText.Substring(6, 2)
    txtBox5.Text = cpText.Substring(8, 2)
    txtBox6.Text = cpText.Substring(10, 2)

    'the event has been handled manually
    e.Handled = True
End If
End Sub
```

Another option is to have one masked textbox event.  Might be easier

Comment: Thanks for your help